# __raw_readl() always returns 0x00 for Freescale i.MX 6 PXP Registers

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, imx6

I am working with a Freescale i.MX6DualLite processor on a custom board. The imx camera HAL supports the SoC's Pixel Pipeline module to convert pixel formats of USB cameras. Therefore, I ported the following kernel driver into my kernel:

https://github.com/boundarydevices/linux-imx6.git

Branch: boundary-imx-o8.0.0_1.0.0-ga

Unfortunatly, accessing the PXP does not work. The ioctl() calls PXP_IOC_CONFIG_CHAN, PXP_IOC_START_CHAN and PXP_IOC_WAIT4CMPLT fail because the PXP interrupt is not triggered.
Therefore I added several printk() statements to check PXP registers:

```
[67221.574349] pxp: HW_PXP_CTRL 0x0
[67221.574352] pxp: HW_PXP_STAT 0x0
[67221.574355] pxp: HW_PXP_OUT_CTRL 0x0
[67221.574357] pxp: HW_PXP_OUT_BUF 0x0
[67221.574360] pxp: HW_PXP_AS_CTRL 0x0
[67221.574363] pxp: HW_PXP_AS_BUF 0x0
[67221.574365] pxp: HW_PXP_PS_CTRL 0x0
[67221.574368] pxp: HW_PXP_PS_BUF 0x0
```

Every relevant register is 0x00. I triple checked clocking mechanism and CCM registers: The PXP has a clock signal. So I assume this is not the problem. I also verified the PXP register address specified in the DTS. It is correct and successfully remapped into my kernel memory. I also played with ioremap_no_cache() but it did not help.

So my question is: Has anyone experienced the same kind of problem with any Freescale i.MX6 module? Is there some kind of enable signal I am missing?

Comment: I can only speculate here. If the device has that hardware block, the register values look like the device is powered on, but lacks of clock signal, that’s why 0x0 are read back (for powered off usually we got 0xffffffff).